# Where is metadata for PDF files? Can I insert metadata into any PDF file?

Tags: linux, pdf, software-rec, file-metadata, tagging

I have many files of music; with the program mp3Tag, I had organized all of it. I have the correct metadata as it allows. I am looking for a free software that does the same, but for PDF files.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/27381/how-to-edit-pdf-metadata-from-command-line

Comment: Please modify your question title. You are NOT interested in the internals of PDF format, it seems, but rather in the names of free s/w which might help you modify pdf metadata. I'm not even sure if it's linux related at all, from the way this question is worded.

Comment: I am Latin, sorry for bad sense fo question. I am in Win10, but I want to know that's too. Win10 shows many columns with Author, Year, and I thinks is for PDf and relationed.

Answer (score 17):

Ghostscript can insert or modify document metadata into any PDF.

***Caveats:*** While doing so, Ghostscript will (1) first read in the complete PDF code, (2) second re-process that complete PDF code, (3) write out a completely new PDF file. This process can be wanted (could be for the advantage of the PDF quality, for example by additionally embedding previously missing fonts) or unwanted...

#### How to do it

1. Create a text file named *mydocinfo.pdfmark* and put the following content into it:

   ```
   [ /Title (Jaziel's Important Document)
     /Author (Jaziel Aguirre)
     /Subject (Mr. Aguirre's experiments with pdfmark)
     /Creator (JA's Metadata Inserter)
     /ModDate (D:19700101000000+01'00')
     /Producer (A 'pdfmark' trick with Ghostscript)
     /Keywords (Metadata, Ghostscript, PDF, Linux)
     /CreationDate (D:20181229104653+01'00')
     /DOCINFO
   pdfmark
   ```

   Note, that the opening `[` does ***NOT*** require a closing `]` -- it is closed by the 'pdfmark' keyword.
2. Now run this Ghostscript command to insert the new metadata into an existing PDF:

   ```
   gs                     \
     -o with-metadata.pdf \
     -sDEVICE=pdfwrite    \
     existing.pdf         \
     mydocinfo.pdfmark
   ```
3. Check the new metadata:

   ```
   pdfinfo with-metadata.pdf

     Title:          Jaziel's Important Document
     Subject:        Mr. Aguirre's experiments with pdfmark
     Keywords:       Metadata, Ghostscript, PDF, Linux
     Author:         Jaziel Aguirre
     Creator:        JA's Metadata Inserter
     Producer:       A 'pdfmark' trick with Ghostscript
     CreationDate:   Sat Dec 29 10:46:53 2018 CET
     ModDate:        Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970 CET
     Tagged:         no
     UserProperties: no
     Suspects:       no
     Form:           none
     JavaScript:     no
     Pages:          1
     Encrypted:      no
     Page size:      142.8 x 202.08 pts
     Page rot:       0
     File size:      5394 bytes
     Optimized:      no
     PDF version:    1.7
   ```

(Tested with Ghostscript v9.27.)

Comment: what a useful, I will do this in some future. thanks

Comment: Mmm Yes, but i am new here, so, I click the up arrow of corner?

Comment: @JaazielAguirre: Exactly. Plus, you pick one (or none) of the answers to make it the *"accepted"* (best) answer for you...

Comment: Does this also allow to remove metadata? If yes, how?

Comment: @holzkohlengrill: Yes, if you create the *mydocinfo.pdfmark* file with zero content inside the brackets, like this: `[ /Title () ....`

Comment: Note, ghostscript no longer allows you to change the /Producer key. See [newer question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/766684/119298).

Answer (score 11):

`pdftk` is a command line utility allowing you to extract and modify the PDFs metadata using the `dump_data` and the `update_info` options.

The following command will extract the metadata of the `input.pdf` to `metadata` file:

```
pdftk input.pdf dump_data output metadata
```

Modify the content of the `metadata` file using your text editor, then update the pdf file to a new `output.pdf`:

```
pdftk input.pdf update_info metadata output output.pdf
```

To check the new pdf file (print to stdout):

```
pdftk output.pdf dump_data
```

Comment: Ha!, I was thinking about adding pdftk's method a little bit later too. Now I can upvote your answer instead... :-)

Comment: Hey, that's is simple.  thanks for response. My ask was for Win10 but it helps me for the future, I had problems with Computers and just now I have a Pc with only win10. thanks

Comment: The format of the `metadata` file created by `pdftk` is hard to understand, so it's hard to edit. In mine there is no “title” nor “author” anywhere and if try to add one by mimicking what's already there, `pdftk` does not seem to like it when I use `update_info`. Does someone know where to find info on the `dump_data` output format?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of writing the metadata into a text file first, you could of course also put it into one single command line:

```
gs -o with-meta.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -f existing.pdf -c "[ /Title (Jaziel's Important Document) /Author (Jaziel Aguirre) /Subject (Mr. Aguirre's experiments with pdfmark) /ModDate (D:19700101000000+01'00') /CreationDate (D:20181120102653+01'00') /Keywords (Metadata, Ghostscript, PDF, Linux) /Creator (JA's Metadata Inserter) /Producer (A 'pdfmark' trick with Ghostscript) /DOCINFO pdfmark"
```

or, with a formatting which is a bit more nice (readable):

```
gs -o with-meta.pdf  \
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -f existing.pdf   \
   -c "[ /Title (Jaziel's Important Document) 
         /Author (Jaziel Aguirre)
         /Subject (Mr. Aguirre's experiments with pdfmark)
         /Keywords (Metadata, Ghostscript, PDF, Linux)
         /ModDate (D:19700101000000+01'00')
         /Keywords (Metadata, Ghostscript, PDF, Linux)
         /Creator (JA's Metadata Inserter)
         /Producer (A 'pdfmark' trick with Ghostscript)
         /CreationDate (D:20181120102653+01'00')
       /DOCINFO pdfmark"
```