# Removing metadata from a PDF

Tags: pdf, file-metadata

What commands must I issue irreversibly to remove all metadata
from `foo.pdf`?  Assume embedded images are already clean.

I got the impression from

https://gist.github.com/hubgit/6078384

that

```
exiftool -all:all= foo.pdf
qpdf --linearize foo.pdf bar.pdf
```

might suffice, but it wasn't clear to me whether it was an
entirely complete method.  There was some talk of `pdftk` and an
"info dictionary" that I didn't understand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is metadata for PDF files? Can I insert metadata into any PDF file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489230/where-is-metadata-for-pdf-files-can-i-insert-metadata-into-any-pdf-file)

Comment: My answer using `pdftk` or `qpdf`:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1300265/632237

Answer (score 14):

There is a tool called [MAT (Metadata Anonymisation Toolkit)](https://tails.boum.org/blueprint/doc/mat/) that can remove metadata from a number of different formats. In Ubuntu, this is how I use it:

```
sudo apt install mat2

mat2 filename.pdf  # you will now end up with a file called filename.cleaned.pdf

mat2 --inplace filename.pdf  # this will overwrite original file with the new one, effectively removing the original file

mat2 --show filename.pdf  # this will show the metadata that will be removed, if any (similar to dry run)
```

Note that the cleaned file will have a smaller or larger filesize compared to the original.

There is a [*lightweight* mode](https://0xacab.org/jvoisin/mat2#notes-about-the-lightweight-mode) (just add `--lightweight`) you can try if the cleaned image with the commands above produced significantly large files, as in pdf files. But this might leave some metadata. Use the `exiftool` command to find out if the cleaned image is still leaking any metadata.

Comment: thanks.   do you happen to know why this can multiply the original size by 9?

Comment: I never tried the tool on pdfs, mostly image files, and it works well on image files. But just tried now on a pdf, the size did increase considerably. It looks like the tool turns the pdf pages into images and then binds them together.

Comment: To whom it may concern: `mat2` will (at least some times) change your PDF version (e. g. from 1.4 to 1.5)

Comment: For my use-case, `mat2` increased the file from 1.1M to 4.4M. I do not suggest it.

Comment: According to [the mat2 README](https://0xacab.org/jvoisin/mat2#notes-about-the-lightweight-mode), there is a "lightweight" mode (with `mat2 -L` or `--lightweight`) that prevents rendering the text as images, but *might* leave some metadata intact.

Comment: @Fritz Thanks! I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
cpdf -remove-metadata input.pdf -o output.pdf
```

I haven't verified it myself, yet but `cpdf` is a very reliable to useful tool, available [here](http://www.coherentpdf.com/), free for non-commercial use, and available as a precompiled binary for linux command line.

And the file size is smaller at the end ;)

Comment: It prints "This demo is for evaluation only. http://www.coherentpdf.com/", reduced file size by 2K, doesn't seem to change metadata: the author and creator software are still there.

Answer (score -2):

Try [Metadata Cleaner](https://flathub.org/apps/details/fr.romainvigier.MetadataCleaner) on flathub.

Comment: This uses `mat2` under the hood.