# How to stop Ghostscript from adding "Producer" metadata to PDF files

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I processed a PDF file using Ghostscript:

```bash
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -q -o output.pdf input.pdf
```

When I used a text/binary editor to look into the output PDF, I noticed that Ghostscript has added "Producer" metadata to the PDF. Ghostscript added `/Producer(GPL Ghostscript 10.00.0)` to the PDF information dictionary, and also added `<rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:pdf='http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/' pdf:Producer='GPL Ghostscript 10.00.0'/>` to the XMP metadata. How do I stop Ghostscript from adding this metadata?

Comment: @ChrisDavies No, that does not answer my question. That question is about adding metadata to PDF files. This question is about stopping Ghostscript from automatically adding "Producer" metadata key and value, which none of the answers there is able to do.

Comment: @ChrisDavies No, that does not answer the question because that method does not work. No matter what `/Producer` value I set, Ghostscript 10.00.0 always causes `/Producer` to be set to `GPL Ghostscript 10.00.0` in the output PDF. What version of Ghostscript are you using?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it is a deliberate choice for Ghostscript to not allow you to
set the DOCINFO /Producer key anymore. See
[this
commit](https://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=commit;h=f03bac8ec2dabfff5583bf6afdd2b77f1885f8ef).
The Producer of the output really is the Ghostscript engine, and this information should be kept as-is to allow readers of the document who have problems with displaying it to be able to trace back to that software, for example a particular release of Ghostscript.

> ```
> pdfwrite - don't honour /Producer key in DOCINFO pdfmark
> author    Ken Sharp <ken.sharp@artifex.com>   
> Mon, 30 Sep 2019 13:40:35 +0100 (13:40 +0100)
> ```

> ```
> Bug #701639 "pdfwrite should not honour the /Producer key in DOCINFO pdfmark"
> ```

> ```
> The Producer in the document information dictionary (and XML Metadata)
> is defined quite clearly as the application which produced the PDF file
> from its native format.
> ...
> This commit removes the ability for DOCINFO pdfmarks to alter the
> Producer, 
> ...
> permit the commercial version of Ghostscript to set the /Producer
> from a pdfmark.
> ```